# Powerpoint - remove embedded data from table

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I pasted a pivot table from excel to powerpoint and chose the embed option when doing so.  The deck is now very large (20MB +) due to the embedded data.  Is there a way to keep the table but just drop the embedded data?

Comment: The [embedded] tag is intended only for embedded systems and embedded programming

Comment: Take a screenshot and just paste the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely because you're copying from a very large Excel workbook. When you embed even one cell from an Excel worksheet, the entire workbook actually gets embedded in the PowerPoint file.

One way around this is to select the information you want to embed, copy/paste it into a new Excel workbook (NOT a new worksheet w/in the workbook), then copy/paste/embed into PPT from the new temporary workbook.

At least this'd work with regular worksheet data; it may not work for Pivot Tables (they'd be dependent on other data that wouldn't get pasted from one worksheet to the other, I'm afraid). But it's worth a shot.